# Access variable value for all users in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs-observables

I have this service variable

> Service:

```
  Users:BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

updating these values in component

```
 this.Service.Users.next([...this.Service.Users.value, ID]);
```

fetching values like this

```
this.Service.Users.subscribe(x=>{

});
```

i want if this variable values is updated by any user it should reflect in all the users component like right now only one who has updated the value has the value other users opened in other browser don't have the updated value.

Thanks

Comment: you are talking about other browsers?? then you need to user WebSockets and send the data to a Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use socket programming in angular for this ,
this is not possible by rxjs observable.